# Sobrepor Widgets - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Quando aciono o

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ContactFound(key, index, model)));
```

Esta tela fica debaixo de um menu (Estilo do instagram).

Gostaria de saber se tem como retornar esta tela acima de todos os widgets. Poderia usar stack mas como não construí o app e refazer usando este método demoraria muito.

Determinado ponto do código tem uma estrutura de decisão na qual dependendo do que ocorrer retorna uma tela diferente.

EXEMPLO:

```
if(decisao == 1){
Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ContactFound(key, index, model)));
}
```

Porém, esta tela retorna por cima de outros widgets menos de um menu na parte inferior que é um `CupertinoTabView` (Estilo do instagram). Como poderia retornar esta tela acima deste menu ?

Comment: Nao ficou claro sua duvida, ao acionar `PushReplacement` ela nao vai empilhar mesmo e sim subistitui a rota atual pela q foi chamada, se você quer empilhar, entao deveria chamar apenas o `Push`.

Comment: Não seria isso. Quando chamo mesmo dessa maneira essa tela de alguma forma fica por baixo do menu do app, como eu disse no post

Comment: Estranho teoricamente era para a tela empilhar em cima da tela atual, mesmo que houvesse uma topbar ou bottombar, sem um pouco de código fica complicado para visualizar. Se nao tiver como por código, nos mostre como esta organizado a estrutura das telas.

Comment: Então, gostaria de postar mas como não é de minha autoria fica complicado. Vou tentar postar algo para ajudar no entendimento da questão.

Comment: @JustCase Editei a pergunta

Comment: Eu dei um olhada no cupertinotabview, ele gerencia o empilhamento das telas, por isso que   a tela esta empilhando por baixo do menu. Na documentacao diz que para empilhar uma tela por cima do cupertinotabview, voce deve chamar o `Navigator.of(rootNavigator: true)` antes de empilhar Ex: `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push( new CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(fullscreenDialog: true, builder: (BuildContext context) => ContactFound(key, index, model));`

Comment: [Exemplo completo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/226f2c1e99accab83d12bfd49e805f8d7d2d3ed6/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_demo.dart#L712) e a
[Doc CupertinoTabView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabView-class.html)

Comment: Cara Funcionou aqui mas some aquela setinha para voltar, e quando dou o pop, buga novamente...enfim você me ajudou muito. Obrigado

Comment: @JustCase crie uma resposta apontando o que você citou nos comentários, para que fique de auxílio caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema que o nosso amigo ai. 
PS: Coloque os links também que são de grande ajuda.

Comment: Ainda bem, ja é alguma coisa. Quando chegar em casa irei reproduzir por completo esse caso, utilizo pouco o pacote do cupertino, entao fiquei limitado em ajuda lo, e irei melhorar a reposta depois que ver por completo.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com alguns parametros no bloco de decisão app então esta ok até então kkk muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `cupertinotabview` ele gerencia o estado e histórico de empilhamento das telas, por isso que a tela esta empilhando por baixo do menu. Na documentação diz que para empilhar uma tela por cima do `cupertinotabview` você deve chamar  `Navigator.of(rootNavigator: true)`antes chamar o `Push`.
Ex: `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push( new CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(fullscreenDialog: true, builder: (BuildContext context) => ContactFound(key, index, model))`;

[Exemplo Completo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/226f2c1e99accab83d12bfd49e805f8d7d2d3ed6/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_demo.dart#L712)

[CupertinoTabView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabView-class.html)